# Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 favorite keys don't work

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hotkeys

This is a problem that emerged a few months ago and couldn't find a solution for, the favorite keys do not work anymore in their normal use.

By normal use, I mean pressing the key to open the program in task bar; if you hold the key to show pinned items or hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to start the program as administrator, they all work.

So it is definitely not a hardware issue, the keys are all working.

Here's a screenshot showing the faulty keys in blue:

[image]

I have tried the following without success:

- un-install, reboot and re-install the software
- disable all startup programs to see if any are conflicting
- fresh install of Windows 10 (April update)

By looking at mskey.exe, there is definitely something wrong as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is being emitted by the key, obviously this won't work even when tried for real:

[image]

Has anyone experienced the same issue and found a fix for it ?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Yes it does happen in safe mode.

Comment: This is then a problem within Windows itself. I suggest to go into Device Manager and delete the keyboard device, then reboot using the mouse. This will clean-install the driver and may fix the problem without side-effects. If this doesn't help, download and install the driver [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-id/d/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000).

Comment: I believe so but this is also happening on a fresh install. Also, I've already tried what you've mentioned but without success.

Comment: Has something changed on your computer when this started happening, hardware or software? Can you try the keyboard on another computer? If this also happens on another computer, then this is a hardware problem after all.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the drivers on the site of the manufacturer and downloading them?

Comment: Nothing in particular, only Windows updates. The thing is that it is also  happening on a fresh install. I'm going to try on a different computer and let you know. For the drivers I've tried many things, deleting them, safe mode, older version, and so on.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry I forgot to report my testing, please find it on my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Microsoft® Mouse and Keyboard Center 10.4 finally solves the problem !!!

---

I ultimately ended up with five AutoHotKey scripts that work rather well. I've lost the functionality of pinned items but since they require both hands for selection, I guess it's okay to press an extra key with the hand.

The most important part is working and that's a good thing, because switching hundreds of time per day to different programming software, you can imagine that typing thrice as much keys is extremely boring to say the least.

For ones who might have the same issue, here's the first script:

```
#SingleInstance force

SendInput {LWin up}{Alt up}{1 up}{2 up}{3 up}{4 up}{5 up}
Sleep 100

SendInput {LWin down}{1 down}
Sleep 100
SendInput {1 up}{LWin up}

return
```

Change the last block key for the four other scripts, compile as EXE with Ahk2Exe and you're set !

**Edit:**

After trying to track down the cause of the problem, to me, **Windows Version 1709 (Fall Creators Update)** has introduced a regression inducing this problem. It is roughly at this time that I've started encountering this problem (I do install updates as soon as they become available).

Tried on **Windows 7** and they effectively work as expected, one mystery though, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is also emitted but seems to not be ignored anymore on **a recent Windows 10 version**, therefore causing these keys to fail.